# Reusing an alias in the SELECT portion of a hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'd like to reuse an alias within the SELECT portion of a hive query. My use case is to reuse the result of a `case` statement, but I believe this example will suffice:

```
create table testme as select 
  accountid as abc,
  abc as xyz
from account_attributes;
```

Hive complains that 'abc' can't be found.

Any suggested workarounds?

Comment: use accountid instead. an alias can't be used in the same level.

Comment: The point is that I need to reuse the result of a case statement - not just a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table testme as select 
  accountid as abc,
  accountid as xyz
from account_attributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using a subquery like this

```
create table testme as  
select abc, abc as xyz from (
  accountid as abc
from account_attributes
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use alias of expression in select only in the upper subquery.

```
select abc, 
       abc as something,
       abc+account_id as abc_plus_accountid,
       accountid
   from
(select accountid as abc,
        accountid 
  from account_attributes )s
;
```

Also you can use macro:

```
create temporary macro abc(id int) case when ... then ... end;
```

and use it in the query:

```
select abc(accountid) as abc, 
       abc(another_id) as abc2
 from table;
```

Note, macro is not a function, Hive substitutes it's name with a body, replacing parameters each time it appears in the query, before execution. In the macro example above, `(id int)` is a parameter, not a column name, so you can call it with different parameters: `abc(accountid) as abc`, `abc(another_id) as abc2`. Read important version information here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/DropMacro